# Cmake libssh.so.4: version LIBSSH_4_8_1 not found

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cmake, libssh, libyang

I've been trying to build libyang on Ubuntu 22.04, and I keep running into this issue when running cmake:

```
cmake: usr/local/lib/libssh.so.4: version `LIBSSH_4_8_1' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4)
```

I couldn't find anything on this anywhere. I have libssh-dev 0.9.6-2build1 installed and cmake version 3.22.1-1ubuntu1.

The error comes up when running cmake from anywhere, so I guess it's related to cmake itself?

Edit: For extra context, I've been trying to set up Netopeer2 using this guide: http://www.seguesoft.com/index.php/netconfc/free-trial-netconfc/2-uncategorised/1-setup-netopeer2

Comment: Okay so now the same error appeared when using "git clone" too, which feels a bit unrelated. I built and installed an older version of libssh earlier (0.8.6), although I did install the newest version after that. Maybe that broke something?

Comment: The file `libssh.so.4` on Ubuntu 22.04 is placed under `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssh.so.4`: https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/amd64/libssh-4/filelist. Looks like you have **another installation** of libssh library, which conflicts with the system installation.

Comment: "/usr/local/lib/libssh.so.4" is an obstacle. `libyang` builds OK with the Ubuntu 22.04 provided `libssh-dev` : ........ `sudo apt install libcurl4-gnutls-dev libssh-dev libpcre2-dev graphviz doxygen`

Answer (score 0):

So basically libssh is having conflicting versions in this case, I would recommend first doing ths command

> ls /usr/local/lib/libssh*

This lists all the libssh versions you have. After which you should remove all the listed distributions, in this case being.

> sudo rm /usr/local/lib/libssh.so.4

and so on. After this either do

> sudo apt install libssh-dev

or also just directly clone using

> git clone http://git.libssh.org/projects/libssh.git

and build from there. This is it. Hope it helps. Thank you.
I also recommend to not use that link exactly. A better sequence for installing netopeer2, is to first install libyang, then libnetconf2 inside it, after which you install netopeer2. This provides a successful compilation. Sysrepo can be directly sudo installed.

Note: Worked in my case I don't know if it will work for yours.